# Adding parameters to DefaultShell in Windows OpenSSH Server (e.g. powershell.exe -NoLogo)

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh, sshd

I have Windows OpenSSH server installed and working properly.  I can change the default shell that is ssh'd into using `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH` and adding a `DefaultShell` property as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows).

So let's go with the default example, since it works as-is on pretty much every Windows installation with the "normal" `C:\Windows` path:

`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force`

Now let's say that I want to add a parameter to it, perhaps "-NoLogo".  This is just a for-instance.  Ultimately, I'd want to be able to launch into a WSL distribution with options.  But for now, let's go simple:

`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo" -PropertyType String -Force`

This not only doesn't work, it breaks the login in strange ways.  With the first method (no arguments), my public key in ssh-agent is offered and accepted.  When I add the `-NoLogo`, I end up at a password prompt, which fails using my Windows password.

Running `sshd.exe -ddd` shows:

```
User not allowed because shell c:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -nologo does not exist
```

Okay, so that's not going to work, because OpenSSH checks to make sure the exact `DefaultShell` string is an executable.

I [see](https://superuser.com/a/1381509/1210833) that there are two other registry settings, but neither seems to be what I'm looking for.  One might think from its name that `DefaultShellCommandOption` would be of some use here, but it is simply the option needed for the shell when a *command* is passed in, such as:

```
ssh hostname ls
```

Since one of the attempted answers here thought `DefaultShellCommandOption` would do the trick, I did try it, and confirmed that it is only used when a command is passed in.  I can also see in the OpenSSH source that shell_option is only used when there is a command, otherwise it only executes the shell by itself:

```
if (command) {
    size_t len = strlen(shell) + 1 + strlen(shell_option) + 1 + strlen(command) + 1;
    pty_cmd = calloc(1, len);

    strcpy_s(pty_cmd, len, shell);
    strcat_s(pty_cmd, len, " ");
    strcat_s(pty_cmd, len, shell_option);
    strcat_s(pty_cmd, len, " ");
    strcat_s(pty_cmd, len, command);
} else {
    pty_cmd = shell;
}
```

Is anyone aware of a way to add parameters/arguments to the `DefaultShell` in Windows OpenSSH?

Comment: @Martin-Prikryl If you come back and read this - Even though your (now deleted) answer was wrong, I wouldn't have found my answer if I hadn't tried yours out.  So thanks for the attempt!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Potential Workaround

Once I noticed that OpenSSH was checking to make sure the `DefaultShell` existed and was executable, I decided to just try creating a batch file wrapping the PowerShell options.

I created a directory and file `C:\ProgramData\OpenSSH\ssh-shell.bat`:

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -NoLogo %*
```

And changed my `DefaultShell` to run that wrapper (from an elevated PowerShell):

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\ProgramData\OpenSSH\ssh-shell.bat" -PropertyType String -Force
```

That seems to work as desired, both for access to the shell itself as well as when running with a command (e.g. `ssh hostname ls`).

It is also possible to launch directly into a specified WSL distribution this way:

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe ~ -d Alpine %*
```

Note that this does require that the `DefaultShellCommandOption` also be changed:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShellCommandOption -Value "-e /bin/sh -c" -PropertyType String -Force
```

##### Security Implications

This *feels* like it is just as safe as the default OpenSSH `DefaultShell` behavior, since it builds the commandline using the actual shell (plus my desired additional arguments), the `DefaultShellCommandOption` (`-c` by default), and the command(s) that are passed in.

But I'm open to suggestions on how this might be made more robust or secure, or if there are any security issues that one might see.