# Docker Remote Containers - Remote Access Issue (Mac M1 -> Windows WSL 2)

Tags: ssh, docker, wsl2

I have successfully setup remote access to my Windows 10 machine running openSSH Server (using public key authentication). I am also running Docker Desktop on my Windows machine.

I would like to access the docker daemon and containers on the windows machine from my Macbook M1 (so I can control applications running in a container on the windows machine and develop scripts for that application).

I basically got the idea from [this article](https://leimao.github.io/blog/VS-Code-Development-Remote-Host-Docker/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20VS%20Code,hostname%22%20to%20VS%20Code%20settings)

I can successfully connect with ssh to the Windows machine (the openSSH server is installed on WSL 2 and not inside a linux distro):

My daemon.json on Windows:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                            
  "registry-mirrors": [],                                                                                                                                                    
  "insecure-registries": [],                                                                                                                                                 
  "debug": false,                                                                                                                                                            
  "experimental": false,                                                                                                                                                     
  "features": {                                                                                                                                                              
    "buildkit": true                                                                                                                                                         
  },                                                                                                                                                                         
  "builder": {                                                                                                                                                               
    "gc": {                                                                                                                                                                  
      "enabled": true,                                                                                                                                                       
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB"                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                        
  },                                                                                                                                                                         
  "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "ssh://0.0.0.0:2376"],                                                                                                                     
  "group": "docker"                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

On the Macbook I have installed [docker file](https://download.docker.com/mac/static/) and set DOCKER_HOST:

```
echo "export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://phili@192.168.0.11:22" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

I also tried using contexts as described in [this MS article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/ssh)

I can then run docker commands on my Macbook and see the remote docker host and the running containers:

```
phil@Phil-MacBook:~ > docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:55:20 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.6
  Git commit:       75249d8
  Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:52:10 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.9
  GitCommit:        e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1
  GitCommit:        v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

```
phil@Phil-MacBook:Docker > docker ps    
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS         PORTS                                                 NAMES
6449bc460e6b   humble_bumble                                 "jupyter notebook --…"   5 days ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:2375->2375/tcp, :::2375->2375/tcp, 8888/tcp   priceless_mahavira
153b9fcb70a9   vsc-docker-0f0a12d517505d0b19ef9dcb95ae109f   "jupyter notebook --…"   6 days ago   Up 12 hours    8888/tcp                                              gracious_nash
```

I created a `.devcontainer` containing `dockerfile` and `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
        "name": "DEV ENV",
        "dockerFile": "dockerfile",
        "runArgs": ["--init"],
        "mounts": [ "source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker-host.sock,type=bind" ],
        "overrideCommand": false,

        // Use this environment variable if you need to bind mount your local source code into a new container.
        "remoteEnv": {
                "LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER": "${localWorkspaceFolder}"
        },

        // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
        "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
        },

        // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
        "extensions": [
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
                "kelvin.vscode-sshfs",
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-toolsai.jupyter"
        ],

        // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
         "forwardPorts": [80,8080,5000,8888,2375]

        // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
        // "postCreateCommand": "docker --version",

        // Comment out connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
        //"remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

In VS Code (most current release) on Macbook M1 I installed **Remote Containers** and also get the running dockers listed:

[image]

However, when I try to `open folder in container`, it does some things successfully but then the following error aborts the process:

```
[2021-10-07T15:11:01.391Z] failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to process "\"dev": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
[2021-10-07T15:11:01.394Z] Stop (6252 ms): Run: docker build -f /Users/phil/docker/.devcointainer/dockerfile -t vsc-devcointainer-b8e915c60b425e8ebf3b4086823c8d79 /Users/phil/docker/.devcointainer
[2021-10-07T15:11:01.399Z] Command failed: docker build -f /Users/phil/docker/.devcointainer/dockerfile -t vsc-devcointainer-b8e915c60b425e8ebf3b4086823c8d79 /Users/phil/docker/.devcointainer
```

When I try `Attach to running container`:

```
[6588 ms] Start: Preparing Extensions
[6589 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/home/devuser/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/home/devuser/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/home/devuser/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[6593 ms] Error: stream ended with:297 but wanted:1128865906
        at u (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:7:60200)
        at /Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:7:60381
        at s (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:12:5296)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:12:5466)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
        at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
[6594 ms] Remote-Containers server terminated (code: 126, signal: null).
[6597 ms] 
[6597 ms] 
[6597 ms] Exit code 1
[6599 ms] Extensions cache, install extensions: None
[6599 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /home/devuser/.vscode-server/extensionsCache && ls /home/devuser/.vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[6605 ms] kelvin.vscode-sshfs-1.23.0
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker-1.17.0
ms-python.python-2021.9.1246542782
ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.9.4
ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap-1.0.0
[6606 ms] 
[6606 ms] Extensions cache, copy to remote: None
[6607 ms] Start: Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink /proc/$pid/cwd ; readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt ; cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "
[6641 ms] Start: Starting VS Code Server
[6642 ms] Start: Run in container: /home/devuser/.vscode-server/bin/7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e/server.sh --log debug --force-disable-user-env --port 0 --extensions-download-dir /home/devuser/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --start-server 
[6645 ms] Error: stream is closed
        at /Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:12:3742
        at i (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:12:1874)
        at EventEmitter.t.<computed> [as exec] (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:12:1636)
        at u (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:128:1024)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at /Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:128:1002
        at Ln (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:171:1779)
        at JB (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:171:541)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
        at async Ci (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:143:7538)
        at async pF (/Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:284:1663)
        at async /Users/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.194.3/dist/extension/extension.js:314:1497
[16614 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
```

I feel I am close to success since I can see the containers in VS Code, but obviously I am missing something. Could it have to do with different architectures (Macbook M1 is ARM and Windows is x86)?