# Automatically run commands after SSH login to Windows server

Tags: ssh, openssh, windows-server, sshd

Is there a way to run commands automatically when user logs in with SSH to Windows Server?

I tried to implement this using the `AutoRun` in Command Processor registry, which runs commands when any `cmd.exe` is started, but due to the complexity of the script in question, this just ends up in endless recursion every time no matter how I try to fix the situation.

I also don't want to run these commands when it's not SSH, but if it's a working option to check it's the first `CMD`, not anything spawned inside it, I can check the existence of `SSH_TTY` variable to exclude non-ssh logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to configure the default shell to be your script and have it execute the real shell at the end.

```
echo Welcome to my server

%COMSPEC%
```

See [Configure default shell initialized by OpenSSH on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/1182522/213663#1381509).

Comment: Ah, of course. I did read that but assumed it must be a real shell... Just a simple .bat with "call xxx.bat" and cmd.exe in it did the trick. Thanks.